# "SSL Errors Occurred Accessing URL" after upgrade to Lyon

Tags: ubuntu, qgis-2.12

I just upgraded to QGIS Lyon in `Ubuntu 14.04` using either `ubuntugis` or the `debian` repo. When opening QGIS I get the following error screen:

[image: Error message]

When I click on "Connection Certificates", the following window appears:

[image: Certificate Information]